# Define a class property based on another own property

Tags: typescript

I have this basic class where I would like for `location` to be a direct property of `CameraEvent`. At the moment it's being accessed via a get method `get location()`.

Does creating the get/set method make it a direct property of `CameraEvent`? Even if it's not being defined directly (as private prop).

```
class CameraEvent {

  private _camera: Camera;
  // dynamic location

  constructor(camera: Camera) {
    super();

    this._camera = camera;
  }

  // camera getter/setter

  get location(): CameraLocation {
    return this._camera.cameraLocation;
  }

  set location(value: CameraLocation) {
    this._camera.cameraLocation = value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does creating the get/set method make it a direct property of CameraEvent

Yes. Your `get` / `set` exist on instances of `CameraEvent`

> Even if it's not being defined directly (as private prop).

If you define a private getter/setter, it can only be accessed within the class.